# Dates are in a different format since moving the DB to a different server

Tags: sql, date

On my website, some dates are shown after i read them from the DB. 
The dates were shown in a dd/mm/yyyy format.
After moving my DB to a different server the format changed to mm/dd/yyyy and i can't find the reason why. I tried to change the language to British English on Microsoft SQL management so the dates now should be shown in the dd/mm/yyyy format but on the website it is still not updated. I also tried to change the date preferences on the DB server and that didn't help either.

What can be the reason for the format change?

Thanks.

Comment: what database are you using (question applies to original server and different server)?  You can change the format of dates in the select statement that you are retrieving your data from, it's relatively simple to move it to a different format.  Need to know what server you are on to give specific syntax though

Comment: I'm using sql server 2014.

Comment: Not sure if I can tell you why they changed...but I generally treat database dates as format agnostic anyway, as long as they are stored, does the format really matter?  Use formatting (convert for example) to bring the date into whatever format you want to display and don't worry about what it is in the database

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of resources online that feature changing date and time formats for an operating system. The dialog, at least in recent versions of Windows, can be found through searching the Start menu for "Change Date, Time, or Number Formats" and it opens the Region dialog. That will set the *default* setting for date formats in most programs.

But really, unless we're just talking about results returned in SSMS (in which case I wouldn't expect this to matter that much?), this is a prime example of why server-side code should *generally* be explicit about how numbers should be formatted, and said format should be universally accepted. Otherwise you come across issues like this, where suddenly users are confronted with new regional settings and logs are no longer consistent and it's just harder for everyone.

But it should be resolved if you check that dialog and fix the settings appropriately.